# how would I compare a specific value without using new if statement?

Tags: javascript, loops, class, object, if-statement

I used loop for comparing every each one of the values from 2 different Objects'. Because when I want to change the variables, this way is more simple and readable rather than just using massive `if` `if` `if` ... to compare all of the values 1 by 1 every single time.

This is the code:

```
  // Get values from the default and options
  var defaultValues = Object.values(this.getDefaults),
  newValues = Object.values(this.options);

  // Used loop for counting every single values from the Objects' 
  var checkDef = defaultValues.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur),
      checkNew = newValues.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);

  // Compare between those 2 different variables.
  if (checkDef === checkNew) {
    console.log('true');
    setInterval(() => {
      this.runAnimate(this.initial[1], 1)
    }, this.getDefaults.countdown);
  } else {
    console.log('false');
    setInterval(() => {
      this.runAnimate(this.initial[1], 1)
    }, this.options.countdown);
  }
```

but how would I write the code when if I want to run a different `function` based on the different conditions?

At first I tried to make new `if` statement but it would've caused unnecessary checking(literally, double checking) since I've compared whole the values by using loop the above. Thus, giving another `if` is just totally wasting imo.

```
  // Give another if to compare a specific condition
  if (this.getDefaults.skew === this.options.skew) {
     // ... execute function1
  else {
     // ... execute function2
  }
```

Is this unavoidable to give another `if` statement for comparing specific values in my case?

==== Progress Update ====

My goal is when the value called `pcSwipe` is `true`, run the `mousedown, swipeMove, swipeEnd` function by executed `$el.on({mousedown: ... })`. but like I said on the comment, `mousedown` function runs multiple times by numbers of the conditions how many each of the values are `true` between `getDefaultValues` and `options`. And this causes the same ways to `mobile`. it moves 7 times row (because `true` is 7) when you swipe the screen on the mobile statement.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Quaza/dub6L328/7/)

```js
(function ($, window, undefined) {
  class Slider {
    // Get the default values
    get getDefaults() {
      const defaults = {
        autoSlide : true,
        countdown : 4000,
        direction : "left",
        display   : 1,
        loop      : true,
        pcSwipe   : false,
        verticle  : false,
        skew  : true,
      }
      return defaults;
    }
    constructor(options, initial) {
      this.getDefaults;
      this.initial = initial;
      this.initial[0].css({left: -100 + '%'});
      this.options = Object.assign(this.getDefaults, options);
    }

    // Swipe Event for PC
    mousedown(e) {
      console.log('text');
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    swipeMove(e) {

    }
    swipeEnd(e) {

    }

    // Swipe Event for Mobile
    mdtouchStart(e) {
      this.coordX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      this.coordY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      return this.coordX, this.coordY;
    }
    mdtouchMove(e, initial) {
      var tx = e.touches[0].clientX,
      ty = e.touches[0].clientY,
      dist = Math.sqrt(tx + this.coordX);
    }
    mdtouchEnd(e, initial, defaults) {
      var dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX,
        flood;
      if (dist > 200) {
        flood = -1;
        this.runAnimate(this.initial[1], flood);
      } else if (dist < -200) {
        flood = 1;
        this.runAnimate(this.initial[1], flood);
      } else {
        console.log('do nothing');
      }
      console.log(dist, this.initial[1]);
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    // Set the function
    runAnimate(frame, direction) {
      if (!this.initial[1].is(':animated')) {
        this.initial[0].stop(true, true).animate({
          left: '-=' + (direction * 100) + '%'
        }, () => {
          this.initial[4] += direction;
          if (this.initial[4] > this.initial[5]) {
            this.initial[4] = 1;
            this.initial[0].css({
              left: -100 + '%'
            });
          } else if (this.initial[4] == 0) {
            this.initial[4] = this.initial[5];
            this.initial[0].css({
              left: (this.initial[5] * (-100)) + '%'
            });
          }
        })
      }
    }

    // Execute Method
    exe($el, initial, getDefaults) {
      console.log('no.4');

      // Distract values from the default and options

      Object.keys(this.getDefaults).forEach(key => {
        if (this.getDefaults[key] == this.options[key]) {
          $el.on({
            mousedown : (e) => this.mousedown(e),
            onmousemove : (e) => this.swipeMove(e),
            onmouseup   : (e) => this.swipeEnd(e, initial, getDefaults)
          });
        } else {
          $el.on({
            touchstart: (e) => this.mdtouchStart(e),
            touchmove : (e) => this.mdtouchMove(e),
            touchend  : (e) => this.mdtouchEnd(e, initial, getDefaults)
          });
        }
      });

      // Compare between those 2 different value bundles
      // var checkDef = defaultValues.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur),
      //     checkNew = newValues.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
      // if (checkDef === checkNew) {
      //   console.log('true');
      //   setInterval(() => {
      //     this.runAnimate(this.initial[1], 1)
      //   }, this.getDefaults.countdown);
      // } else {
      //   console.log('false');
      //   setInterval(() => {
      //     this.runAnimate(this.initial[1], 1)
      //   }, this.options.countdown);
      // }
    }
  }
  $.fn.bluSlider = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      const $el = $(this);
      const initials = [
        myFrame = $el.find('.wrap'),
        myItems = myFrame.find('a'),
        myCloneFirst = myItems.first().before(myItems.last().clone()),
        myCloneLast = myItems.last().after(myItems.first().clone()),
        myCount = 1,
        myLength = myItems.length
      ];
      var Proto = new Slider(options, initials);
      Proto.exe($el);
    })
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.inline-grid').bluSlider({
  skew: false,
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      html, body
      {
        background-color: black;
      }

      .span2 {
        color: blue;
      }
      div {
        position: relative;
      }
      .inline-grid, .inline-grid2, .inline-grid3 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 560px;
        border: 7px solid teal;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;

        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
      }
      .cell {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        flex-shrink: 0;

        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .orange {
        background-color: orange;
      }
      .blue {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      .crimson {
        background-color: crimson;
      }
      .green {
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slider" class="inline-grid">
      <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#" class="cell orange">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell blue">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell crimson">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell green">

        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="slider2" class="inline-grid2">
      <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#" class="cell orange">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell blue">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell crimson">

        </a>
        <a href="#" class="cell green">

        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the properties:

```
Object.keys(this.getDefaults).forEach(key => {
    if (this.getDefaults[key] == this.options[key]) {
        // execute function1
    } else {
        // execute function2
    }
});
```

Comment: This way is executing the function multiple time as many values as the `getDefaults` has. I've tried to add the touch methods and it executed 7 times by one click.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to check every value, but not write lots of `if` statements.

Comment: You understood correct. Maybe I need to put all of the code in the question for more clearly.

Comment: Yes, please add more code to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: The code you posted has my answer in it, but you said that's not correct. Show your code that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: I edited again more understandable. could you please 1 more check?

Comment: If you only want to check one option, then you don't need a loop, you just need one `if` statement.

Comment: Why are you comparing the option to the default? What I suspect you really want to do is use the option, but if the option isn't set use the default insteead. This is usually done by merging the options and defaults, like `var settings = Object.assign({}, this.options, this.getDefaults);

Comment: ._. I didn't think that way to solve this problem. Maybe I should try that way, overriding a whole object to the target and using if statement when I need to turn on/off the function. Thank you for answering and commenting.

Comment: What I want you to put in the question is the original code that has too many `if` statements, because that's what you said the problem was.